# Any digitized text that marks the shva na?

Tags: tanach, grammar-dikduk, text

Does anyone know of any downloadable digitized text that marks the 'shva na's?

For now, I am looking specifically for a text of Megilas Ester. But I would appreciate all of Tanach and also the siddur.

As a bonus, does anyone know an easy ASCII or equivalent code to change the look of a shva to differentiate the shva na's from the shva nach's?

Comment: There are certain fonts that have the rules programmed, otherwise you have to know them.

Comment: There is no Unicode standard for sheva na IIRC, so anytime you find will have to be custom.

Comment: @Kazibácsi interesting, where can I find such a font?

Comment: You can activate them using stylistic sets of professional (and quite expensive) fonts. ארץ הצבי is one such font, but it's ugly in my humble view.

Comment: Another example: http://www.masterfont.co.il/Pdf/Nikud_Features.pdf

Comment: I don't want this thread to get too sidetracked by the 'bonus' question. I really would appreciate an answer to where one could get a digitized text that indicates shva na's.